# List all users and last time they read mail, pipeing to multiple output

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I have one system that I would like to do a little clean up, so I would like to get all user accounts and last date they accessed they mail. It is a Debian system.

So far I got to this:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | xargs -n1 finger | grep "Mail last read"
```

But I dont know how to write that username in front of Mail last read Sun Aug 12 03:06 2012 (CEST)

Thank you
edit: this is sample finger output:

```
/bla# finger xxxxx
Login: xxxxx                         Name: xxxxx xxxxx
Directory: /home/xxxxx               Shell: /bin/true
Never logged in.
Mail last read Sun Aug 12 03:17 2012 (CEST)
No Plan.
```

Comment: also asked on Unix&Linux: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45714/4667

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the -B option:

```
... | grep -B3 "Mail last read" | awk '/Login:/ {name=$2} /Mail last read/ {print name, $0}'
```

assuming that the line containing "Login:         Name: " appears 3 lines before the mail status in the output of finger. The `awk` command prints the 2nd field of the first line of the output from grep, as well as the line containing the mail status.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, but it does not work :( I only get Mail last read Sat Aug 11 23:54 2012 (CEST) x times...coplete code is `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | xargs -n1 finger | grep -B3 "Mail last read" | awk 'NR==1 {print $2} /Mail last read/ {print}'`

Comment: Could you add the full output of your `finger` command to the question? It's possible that 3 lines of context aren't enough in your case (e.g., `-B4` may work).

Comment: I edited the mail question, and this is command `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | xargs -n1 finger | grep -B5 "Mail last read" | awk 'NR==1 {print $2} /Mail last read/ {print}'` but I got the same output, only Mail last read Sun Aug 12 01:36 2012 (CEST)....

Comment: Try my updated solution. I'm not sure why you were only getting the mail line before, but this update fixes a problem where I assumed output for just a single user.